# WindowsPhone 7 Screenshots

Tags: windows-phone-7, screenshot

How to create such cool presentation screenshots like this:
[image]

or this
[image]

I've seen this many times. Seems to be a standard application to create such wide screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always going to be a bit of a manual process, taking screenshots and stitching them together. However, the panorama control adds an extra complication, the parallax effect on the bcakground means that your screenshots will not meet up! To get around this, you can disable the parallax as described here:

http://www.markusegger.com/Blog/Development.aspx?messageid=68e6dfd4-c761-4218-ba83-cf28ca2a8264

The rest is all down to your photoshop skillz ;-)

Answer (score 3):

These are promotional images only and are almost certainly created in PhotoShop or some other imaging application.

You can get a lot of design resources and assets from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637515(VS.92).aspx

Comment: Agreed, that screenshot looks like it was based on the PSDs that ship with the design templates.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably if you want to do such a thing you are the author of the application, or you work with the author. In this case you have the 2000x800 bitmap used for the panorama background and it won't be very hard to superimpose a snap of the emulator over it. Personally I think Photoshop is a pig of a thing and I only have mad skillz with Paint.